# How to scroll scrollView when softKeyBoard pops up in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have scroll view inside my ConstraintLayout which should be scrollable, but when my softKeyboard pops up, it is not scrollable at all. Do you have any workarounds? I have tried all parametres of windowSoftInputMode in Manifest file. Here is my screens
[This is my  scrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nk1F.png)

[This my screen when softkeyboard pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV7x6.png)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardView_background">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearAgree"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_warning"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnContinue"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline33"
        app:layout_goneMarginBottom="5dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkboxAgree"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkboxText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/agreement_with_terms_of_use_chekbox"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/back_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline33"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline34">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/back_arrow_ic" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/back_btn"
            android:textColor="@color/greey"
            android:textFontWeight="500"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupWordCount"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_imp_words_outline"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline36"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline33"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtAssuring">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btn12Words"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_bcg_rdbtn"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/import_mnemonics_twelve_words_btn"
            android:textColor="@drawable/toggle_selector_text_color_words"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btn24Words"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_bcg_rdbtn"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/import_mnemonics_twenty_four_words_btn"
            android:textColor="@drawable/toggle_selector_text_color_words"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll12Words"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearAgree"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline36"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline33"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroupWordCount">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt121"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edt_mnemonic_green"
                    android:hint="1."
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:tag="121"
                    android:textColor="@color/actual_color_mnemonic"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt122"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edt_mnemonic_green"
                    android:hint="7."
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:tag="122"
                    android:textColor="@color/actual_color_mnemonic"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt123"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edt_mnemonic_green"
                    android:hint="2."
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:tag="123"
                    android:textColor="@color/actual_color_mnemonic"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt124"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edt_mnemonic_green"
                    android:hint="8."
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:tag="124"
                    android:textColor="@color/actual_color_mnemonic"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt125"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edt_mnemonic_green"
                    android:hint="3."
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:tag="125"
                    android:textColor="@color/actual_color_mnemonic"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt126"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edt_mnemonic_green"
                    android:hint="9."
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:tag="126"
                    android:textColor="@color/actual_color_mnemonic"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt127"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edt_mnemonic_green"
                    android:hint="4."
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:tag="127"
                    android:textColor="@color/actual_color_mnemonic"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt128"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edt_mnemonic_green"
                    android:hint="10."
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:tag="128"
                    android:textColor="@color/actual_color_mnemonic"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt129"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edt_mnemonic_green"
                    android:hint="5."
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:tag="129"
                    android:textColor="@color/actual_color_mnemonic"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt1210"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edt_mnemonic_green"
                    android:hint="11."
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:tag="1210"
                    android:textColor="@color/actual_color_mnemonic"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt1211"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edt_mnemonic_green"
                    android:hint="6."
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:tag="1211"
                    android:textColor="@color/actual_color_mnemonic"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt1212"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/edt_mnemonic_green"
                    android:hint="12."
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:tag="1212"
                    android:textColor="@color/actual_color_mnemonic"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what is the android:windowSoftInputMode of your activity?